# Pack consecutive duplicates of a particular item in a list into a list of lists

Tags: python

I want to read a list and then, select consecutive particular item from that list to store them in a New_list. Continue reading the list and again, select that particular item from that list and store them as another list in that New_list. Let's give an example:

```
nw_lst = []    
lst = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]    
for i in range(0, len(lst), 1):    
    if lst[i] == 0:
        nw_lst.append(lst[i])
print nw_lst
```

The output I am getting is:

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

I want to get:

[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools as it

result = [list(g) for k, g in it.groupby(lst) if k == 0]
```

Comment: Very nice! Could you please explain what it does?

Comment: @AllaTarighati [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) explains this function quite well. Basically it groups consecutive elements of the iterable based on their equality. If two consecutive elements are different, a new group is started. It then yields tuples `key, group` where `key` identifies the group (in the example it's the original item itself), and `group` is an iterator over the group's elements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works as long as you are only interested in consecutive zeros.
The idea is to make use of the `split` method of string. You just convert your list to string, split it on 1s, and then back to list.

```
lst = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
lst_str = "".join([str(x) for x in lst])
lst_str_zeros = lst_str.split("1")
new_lst = [[int(y) for y in x] for x in lst_zeros if x!=""]

print(new_lst)
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `flag` variable to check the status of the `list` in each iteration.

```
nw_lst = []
tmp = []
flag = 0 
lst = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1] 
for i in lst:
    if i == 0:
        if flag == 0:
            tmp.append(i)
            flag = 1
        else:
            tmp.append(i)
    else :
        flag = 0
    if flag == 0 and len(tmp):
        nw_lst.append(tmp)
        tmp = []
```

Comment: if I change the list, like lst = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]; Then, the code is not working. However, previous two is working fine. Thanks though.